# Proxyquire does not stub

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxyquire

I'm trying to use proxyquire to stub the spawnSync method of the child_process module, but it doesn't work. The `console.log(gitResponse)` in my `index.js` file doesn't return the stubbed string, but the unstubbed response (in this case, the git help text).

Can someone see what I am doing wrong?

/index.js

```
var childProcess = require('child_process');

function init () {
  var gitInit = childProcess.spawnSync('git', ['init']);
  var gitResponse = gitInit.stdout.toString() || gitInit.stderr.toString();
  console.log(gitResponse);
}

module.exports = {
init: init
}
```

/test/indexTest.js

```
var assert = require('assert');
var index = require('../index.js');
var sinon = require('sinon');
var proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

describe('test', function () {
it('tests', function () {

    var spawnSyncStub = function (command, args) {
        return {
          stdout: {
            toString: () => "git init success string"

          }
        };
      };

proxyquire('../index.js', {
        'child_process': {
          spawnSync: spawnSyncStub
        }
      });

index.init();

} 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire#example); should you not be doing something like this:?

```
var assert = require('assert');


var index = proxyquire('../index.js', {
  'child_process': {
    spawnSync: function (command, args) {
      return {
        stdout: {
          toString: () => "git init success string"
        }
      };
    }
  }
});

var sinon = require('sinon');
var proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

describe('test', function () {
  it(
    'tests'
    ,function () {
      sinon.assert.match(index.init(), "git init success string");
    } 
  )
});
```

Comment: I define an object called `const myStub = {}` in the initial describe block and then I add the functions I want to stub to `myStub` as needed in each test `myStub.someFunc = () => 1`. Immediately afterward I define my lib to test `let lib = proxyquire('mylib', {'./required-by-lib':  myStub})`. The docs were not clear to me that the examples are within individual tests.